# ¿Qué formas de cortesía han existido en el español? ¿Qué se usaba antes del "por favor" nacido en el siglo XIX?

Tags: historia, cortesía, español-medieval

Elena Álvarez Mellado nos descubrió hace un ratillo en Twitter:

> Acabo de descubrir a través de esta entrada de [@semevadlalengua](https://twitter.com/semevadlalengua) que la forma "por favor" no apareció hasta el siglo XIX http://www.semevadelalengua.es/?p=549
>
> <sub>[Elena Álvarez Mellado (@lirondos), 10 agosto 2018](https://twitter.com/lirondos/status/1027838801190813696)</sub>

Y efectivamente, en su artículo [*(Mi segundo) Congreso Internacional de Historia de la Lengua Española*](http://www.semevadelalengua.es/?p=549) la filóloga Carlota dBM explica:

> La brillantísima plenaria de Silvia Iglesias fue una introducción a la pragmática histórica a partir del ejemplo de cómo se formulaban las peticiones durante los Siglos de Oro. Por mucho que nos pueda sorprender, la forma habitual de pedir algo entonces era usando el imperativo (*cierra la puerta*), con una compleja interacción con el uso de los tratamientos verbales para los distintos grados de cortesía, mientras que la forma habitual de hacerlo ahora, a partir de preguntas indirectas (*¿podrías cerrar la puerta, por favor?*) no se empleaba en absoluto (**¡y de hecho la forma *por favor* aparece en el  siglo XIX!**).

Sorprendido por el hecho que resalto en negrita me quedé con la duda de la otra parte:

> (...) la forma habitual de pedir algo entonces era usando el imperativo, con una compleja interacción con el uso de los tratamientos verbales para los distintos grados de cortesía.

¿A qué combinaciones se refiere? ¿Qué formas de pedir algo ha habido históricamente, habida cuenta que *por favor* es tan reciente? ¿Se usaban otras formas equivalentes a *por favor*?

Comment: Interesante pregunta - [*Discourse and Pragmatic Markers from Latin to the Romance Languages*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5WgJBAAAQBAJ) solo dice (sobre las formas *por favor/per favore* etc) que `"... other languages including Spanish and Portuguese have` **`gradually developed`** `other forms via nominal periphrasis, such as Spanish` *`por favor."`* sin más. En otras lenguas hay evoluciones de `"the Latin performative verbs QUAESO, ROGO, PRECOR"` ej. rom. *mă rog*, it. *prego*, fr. *je vous en prie*.

Comment: ¿Tal vez algo del estilo de **hagame _x_ el favor**, **hagame _x_ la merced**, **tenga _x_ a bien**, en que **_x_** es sustituido por _usted_, _vuesa merced_, _voacé_, etc según el caso y la época?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Formas de cortesía: XVIII - XIX <sub>(antes que el desarrollo de *"por favor"*)</sub>

El capítulo 4 del trabajo [*Cortesía verbal en el español del siglo XIX*](https://is.muni.cz/th/nyvac/Dizertacni_prace-finalni_verze.pdf) (2016) (*Los actos de habla exhortativos*) detalla este tema.

Es bastante complejo, y qué formas se emplean depende tanto de la relación social entre los participantes como de la situación misma y el tipo de petición. Aquí se detallan los ejemplos que hay en esta sección (hay aún más en el apéndice: *Actos exhortativos:* (p.184-195), y un resumen debajo):

#### 4.1. El análisis de los actos exhortativos impositivos

- **4.1.1. El verbo *poder* en una estructura interrogativa**

  - > 220. Señora, ¿**puede** usted explicarme lo que pasa? [Licenciado, 1869-II:
    >        31]
    > 221. ¿**Podrá** usted evocarla y hacer que yo hable con ella? [Valera, 1878:
    >        78]
  - > 222. ¿**Podrían** ustedes darme razón de una buena doncella y decirme al
    >        mismo tiempo si aquí se reciben avisos para burras de leche? [Luceño,
    >        1897: 13]
    > 223. Y vos que todo lo sabéis, ¿**podríais** explicarme por qué causa el señor
    >        Chambela y Conti se estiman tan poco? [Tamayo, 1852: 20]
  - > 224. Tú, que lo sabes todo, ¿no **podrías** decirme de qué medio me valdré
    >        para que mi amada sea mía (...)? [Valera, 1878: 61]
  - > 225. ¿Podrá usted decirme, amigo mío, usted que há tanto tiempo conoce
    >        al Sr. D. Simplicio, de que le ha provenido ese ataque de locura?
    >        [Licenciado, 1869-II: 34]
- **4.1.2. La declaración de deseo- verbos volitivos**

  - > 226. **Deseo** que V.E. no envíe en el primer momento sino poca gente (...).
    >        [Demostración, 1808-1809: 106]
    > 227. (...) pero antes de entrar en ella **desearía**, que para mi gobierno me
    >        explicase Vd. con franqueza (...), que es lo que generalmente se dice del
    >        (...). [Diálogo, 1808: 1]
    > 228. **Quisiera** que la ampliara V. con otra en que me explicara mejor su
    >        asunto (…). [Alarcón, 1891: 22]
  - > 229. ¿**Quiere** usté abrir á mi primo que baja? – Voy al momento. [Pastor,
    >        1887: 14]
    > 230. ¿**Quiere** usted venir á dictarme al gabinete? – Voy en seguida (…).
    >        [Pastor, 1889: 13]
- **4.1.3. Fórmulas rutinarias**

  - > 231. ¿**Hace usted el favor de** venir á tenerme la escalera? – En seguida, en seguida voy. [Escamilla, 1881: 14]
    > 232. ¿**Tiene usted la bondad de** decirme si es falso este billete? [Luceño,
    >        1897: 13]
    > 233. Señora, ¿**hará usted el favor de** mandar que coloquen mi equipaje en
    >        la habitación que me destine usted? [Barrera, 1878: 14-15]
  - > 234. Pues, **hágame usted el favor**, Anita, **de** llevarlas al gabinete donde el amo tiene las otras. [Zamora, 1872: 6]
    > 235. **Tened la bondad de** decirme por donde saldré más pronto á la calle.
    >        [Olona, 1850: 28]
    > 236. **Hacedme el obsequio de** entregar esta carta á su alteza. [Tamayo,
    >        1852: 66]
    > 237. Oye, Inés, **haz el favor de** ir a la cocina, y ayuda á la pobre Nicolasa.
    >        – Enseguida, mamá. [Vital, 1898: 29]
  - > 238. **Sírvase** V. dar cabida en su apreciable publicación al comunicado
    >        que antecede, (…). [La Idea-II, 1868: 2]
    > 239. **Sírvase** V. poner un sobre a la adjunta. [Laverde, 1874]
- **4.1.4. El verbo necesitar**

  - > 240. Pero, ante todo, **necesito** que me seques estas ropas. [Alarcón, 1993:130]
    > 241. Mañana hay baile. **Necesito** unas flores con mucha frescura. [Tamayo, 1852: 49]
    > 242. …**necesito** que te quedes. [Mota, 1888: 17]
- **4.1.5. Verbos performativos**

  - > 243. **Suplico** á V.M. por segunda vez me espida mi licencia absoluta.
    >        [Narváez, 1837: 39]
    > 244. Os **ruego** que no deis ningún paso que pueda despertar sospechas. [Vega, 1848: 53]
    > 245. Y ya que la ocasión se me presenta, **pido** á Vds. su cooperación en el
    >        congreso para que el partido de las reformas acepte con lealtad la
    >        disminución de los gastos generales del Estado. [Galofre, 1868: 18]
  - > 246. Y aconséjame: te lo suplico. [Crosa, 1892: 13]
    > 247. Habla, que yo te lo pido! [Larra, 1866: 53]
- **4.1.6. Los tiempos verbales presente y futuro**

  - > 248. (…), el día que reciba V. esta, **encargará** unas 20 libras de
    >        boquerones, (…), y lo **mandará** freír procurando que no le engañen, y que
    >        todo esté bien fresco. [Alarcón, 1891: 16]
    > 249. La persona que se hubiere encontrado (...) las **entregará** á D. Lucas
    >        (...). [Constancia, 1852: 4]
    > 250. En fin, Vd. **tomará** sus informes y me **contestará** su determinación,
    >        lo que le suplico. [Montemar, 1848: 22]
    > 251. Ya lo sabes; le **dices** a mi marido que á comprar unas cosas hemos
    >        salido. [Luceño, 1897: 27]
    > 252. Le adviertes que **vendremos** á ultima hora. [Luceño, 1897: 27]
- **4.1.7. Construcciones impersonales**

  - > 253. Ahora **es preciso** que te vayas… [Moreno, 1885: 8]
    > 254. **Es forzoso** separarnos. [Larra, 1866: 92]
    > 255. **Es necesario** que hablemos. [Navarro, 1874: 20]
    > 256. Ciudadano Tiberio, **la ley manda** que hables. [Montemar, 1848: 50]
    > 257. **Ojalá** que Vd., Sr. Márquez, con la superioridad de su talento y fuerza de su palabra, nos revele nuevos misterios (...). [Muñoz, 1849: 34]
    > 258. **Que** no **se** le **haga** ningún mal. [Tamayo, 1860: 70]
    > 259. **Que se** me **pague** y me callaré (…). [Larra, 1859: 40]
- **4.1.8. La fórmula de sugerencia**

  - > 260. ¿**Por qué no** le habla usted? Quizás conseguirá más que yo. [Licenciado, 1869-II: 35]
    > 261. Pero ¿**por qué no** sirves antes á nuestro convidado? [Larra, 1859: 23]
- **4.1.9. La expresión de una condición**

  - > 262. Llevaríais hasta el colmo vuestros favores, **si obtuviérais** para mí el mando de uno de los escuadrones que pasan á la isla de Cuba. [Mota, 1888: 11]
    > 263. Muy Sr. mío: **si creéis** conveniente el publicar en las columnas de
    >        vuestro ilustrado periódico el siguiente romance, os lo agradecerá vuestro
    >        afectísimo (…). [Jueves, 1874: 4]
- **4.1.10. La sintaxis interrogativa positiva y negativa**

  - > 264. Al fin, **¿no me dirás dónde fue?** [Bretón, 1832: 12]
    > 265. Es muy rico. **¿Me da usted otro?** [Alba, 1853: 11]
  - > 266. **Sólo** te pido que hables lo menos posible de Orbajosa. [Galdós, 2006: 122]
    > 267. Por de pronto **no** te pido **más de una cosa.** [Morán, 1861: 24]
  - > 268. Desistid de tan desacordado empeño: os lo ruego **por** la memoria de
    >        mi madre. [Tamayo, 1852: 28]
    > 269. ¡Mamá, déjame ir! ¡Te lo pido **por** la memoria de mi padre!
    >        [Alarcón, 1999: 164]
  - > 270. **Vamos**, **vamos**, es preciso que seas menos duro. [Montemar, 1848: 43]
    > 271. **Oye**, quiero que me llames de tú como en otro tiempo. [Mota, 1888: 13]
    > 272. Ruego, **pues**, con todo el respeto que debo, se hagan presentes á la
    >        Suprema Junta de Gobierno los que considero justos temores (...). [Carreño, 1808-1809: 86]
  - > 273. **Dolorcita**, ¿quiere usted darme esa mano para hacer un regalo? [Licenciado, 1869-II: 45]
    > 274. ¿Podrá **usted** decirme, **amigo mío**, usted que há tanto tiempo conoce
    >        al Sr. D. Simplicio, de qué le ha provenido ese ataque de locura? [Licenciado, 1869-II: 34]
    > 275. **Muy Sr. mío**, si creéis conveniente el publicar en las columnas de vuestro ilustrado periódico el siguiente romance, os lo agradecerá vuestro
    >        afectísimo (...). [Jueves: 1874: 4]

#### 4.2. El análisis de los actos exhortativos no impositivos

- **4.2.1. Expresiones performativas**

  - > 276. Muchas gracias, pero **voy á darle un consejo** (…) … cásense ustedes
    >        como Dios manda. [Pastor, 1889: 23]
    > 277. Sí, señor: y le **aconsejo** á usted que en estos momentos no entre, sería
    >        una imprudencia. [Crosa, 1892: 29]
    > 278. Le **recomiendo** a usted un libro extenso y verdaderamente magistral
    >        sobre D. Francisco de Quevedo que ha publicado en París un sobrino de Próspero Mérimée. [Menéndez y Pelayo, 1946: 271]
- **4.2.2. Construcciones impersonales**

  - > 279. (…) … pero **mejor será** que salgamos á la calle, esta casa debe
    >        encerrar para usted recuerdos tristes. [Escamilla, 1881: 15]
    > 280. **Preciso es** que usted descanse. [Rubí, 1849: 19]
    > 281. Mira, Pepe, sea por lo que fuese, Rafael te ha tomado antipatía, y se
    >        excita siempre que te siente a su lado. **Conviene que** dejes de ir una temporadita por allá. [Galdós, 1894: 258]
- **4.2.3. La sintaxis interrogativa con negación- fórmulas de sugerencia**

  - > 282. **Pero** tía **¿no** se pone usted el sombrero**?** [Casta, 1864: 26]
    > 283. **Pero ¿por qué no** dá usted parte á la policía**?** [Licenciado, 1869-II: 38]
- **4.2.4. Expresiones doxásticas**

  - > 284. Si de algo sirve mi consejo, **creo que** debe usted marcharse y cuando
    >        pase algún tiempo, dentro de una semana o cosa así… [Crosa, 1892: 28]
    > 285. ¿No te reñirá tu amo si te entretienes? **Creo que** debes retirarte.
    >        [Galdós, 1884-II: 110]
    > 286. Yo **creo**, que para ir preparando el terreno, como antes dijimos, convendría que no te dieses á conocer de repente (…). - ¡Qué idea tan
    >        luminosa! [Bermejo, 1882: 34]

Hay esta tabla de resumen en el capítulo **5: conclusión**:

[image]

---

**Nota:** aunque tu fuente dice que la forma *por favor* se desarrolló en el final del siglo XIX, nota que ninguno de los ejemplos en el papel que menciono arriba incluyen esas palabras. La palabra escrita (en general) va un poco detrás del habla del vulgo. De hecho, según Google Ngram, "por favor" no empezó a lograr uso hasta los años 1920:

[image]

---

## Formas de cortesía: el Siglo de Oro

Las formas utilizadas unos siglos antes en el Siglo de Oro son muy similares en forma (utilizando el imperativo, etc.) de los listados arriba, pero con sus propias complicaciones dada la evolución continua del pronombre *vos* y sus implicaciones hasta que el desarrollo del moderno *usted*.

El articulo [*Las formas nominales de tratamiento en el Siglo de Oro*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/literatura/aiso/pdf/06/aiso_6_2_033.pdf) (Francisca Medina Morales) lista unos ejemplos de peticiones de cortesía de esta época:

---

**Información adicional:**

<sup>**1.** [*Los marcadores del discurso y la cortesía verbal en español*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qYkuL5hrxP8C), Elena Landone (2009)</sup>

<sup>**2.** [*«La cortesía verbal en el Siglo de Oro: los actos de habla directivos. Un estudio de pragmática histórica»*](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/articulo?codigo=613769), María Cristobalina Moreno</sup>

<sup>**3.** *Ceremonia y cortesía en la literatura del Siglo de Oro. Un estudio de las formas de tratamiento en español*</sup>

Comment: Excelente y completísima respuesta, pero el autor pregunta por las formas anteriores al s. XIX. Todas las citas son posteriores. ¿Has encontrado alguna anterior?

Comment: Tal y como comenta @FGSUZ, esta es una fantástica respuesta. Ya añadiste más datos, pero parte de ellos no son relevantes para responder la pregunta en sí. Podrías considerar añadir una pregunta hablando de _a partir del siglo XIX_ para que la respuesta a _antes del siglo XIX_ sea más nítida. En todo caso, leeré con detenimiento una vez más esta jugosa respuesta, de la cual estoy muy agradecido!

Comment: Super interesante. Nunca me imaginé que las formas de pedir fueran tantas.