# 'por fa' in place of 'por favor'

Tags: coloquialismos, cortesía, contracciones

En la televisión he escuchado "por fa" en lugar de "por favor". ¿Cuánto tiempo ha estado usando la gente esta contracción? Lo he escuchado en las telenovelas de Univision. ¿Tiene Univision el español mexicano?

Comment: I was hearing this in Mexico as early as 1980, but it may have been used earlier.

Comment: Poco tengo que añadir a la respuesta de @walen, solo que suele escribirse junto: porfa. Y que puede venir acompañada de "please" formando una expresión ciertamente redundante, "porfa please", donde se intensifica el ruego y quizás se le da un tono cursi, infantiloide o pijo.

Comment: En Colombia se usa y también se escucha "**porfis**".

Comment: No voy a añadir mucho así que queda como comentario: en Argentina son comunes *porfa* y *porfis*. Últimamente en tono jocoso también se viene oyendo *mildis* (por *mil disculpas*).

Answer (score 5):

En España también se usa, de manera habitual, y diría que desde hace bastantes años, así que no creo que sea algo exclusivo del español mexicano ni del de América en general.

En el CORDE no aparece ningún ejemplo de la expresión, lo cual hace pensar que apenas se usaba antes de 1974.
En el CREA aparecen [ejemplos del año 2001](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=4&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=040519%5C021%5CC000O04052019213712864.1012.1008&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20por%20fa%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCREA%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto4) (hay un falso positivo de 1979 que en realidad es una persona tartamudeando).
En Google Books aparece usada en [una publicación de 1992](https://books.google.es/books?id=WMEuAAAAYAAJ&q=%22por%20fa%22&dq=%22por%20fa%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2w_OU0ILiAhXR0eAKHSJuCmUQ6AEIRDAF), dentro de los diálogos de una obra de teatro, aunque no sé si la obra es de ese año o anterior.

**Esto situaría el origen de esta forma abreviada alrededor de 1990.**

La verdad es que para mí es una expresión que he oído "de siempre", pero también es cierto que mis recuerdos no se remontan mucho más allá de la década de los 90, así que...

Answer (score 0):

El ejemplo más temprano que he encontrado es de **los años setenta**:

> — Primero bota esto pa fuera, por-fa.
>   ...
>   Bota esto pa fuera, por-fa <sup>129</sup>.
>   ...
>   ¿Por-fa, cásese conmigo?
>
> - [*Obra escogida: novela, cuento, ensayo, epistolario*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QmbjTmAVkD8C&pg=PA34&dq="por+fa") (1979)

---

Nota que *por favor* si mismo es una frase relativamente nueva, viendo su primero uso en el siglo XIX:

[¿Qué formas de cortesía han existido en el español? ¿Qué se usaba antes del "por favor" nacido en el siglo XIX?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27054/qu%C3%A9-formas-de-cortes%C3%ADa-han-existido-en-el-espa%C3%B1ol-qu%C3%A9-se-usaba-antes-del-por)

que esta forma de acortamiento de palabras/frases es muy común en castellano (e.j. *finde, cine*):

> p**o**r fav**o**r [p**o**r]/*fa* (AP)
>
> En relación con este fenómeno, propio del registro informal, L. Gómez Torrego [observa](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=oHcdAQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22por+fa%22) que "incluso los jóvenes emplean la forma de cortesía "porfa" [(Umbral, *porfa*)]<sup>1</sup> en lugar de «por favor»...".
>
> - [*El vocabulario, contribución a su didáctica*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IQeOi6QJJ0MC&pg=PA125&dq="porfa") (p.125), Dalila Fasla (1999)

Y que en adición a "porfa" hay las otras formas acortadas (más infántiles) "porfi" y "porfis".

Esto es [el primero](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/porfa-llevame-este-finde-al-cine-6918/) ejemplo de inclusión en un diccionario o lexicon que he encontrado:

> **porfa** [por favor] (fam): no digas esas cosas, *porfa* (Please)
>
> - [Newspaper Spanish: A Vocabulary of Administrative and Commercial Idiom : with English Translations](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lUUOAQAAMAAJ&q="porfa") (1995)

---

<sup>1. Esto implica que hay ejemplos de su uso también en o la obra *Mortal y rosa* (1975) o *Trilogía de Madrid* (1984).</sup>